# Extra "lib64" added to the CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH when building tensorflow with GPU support

Tags: linux, docker, tensorflow, debian

I am trying to build Tensorflow from source with GPU support for a specific CUDA and CuDNN version. Given I know the specific versions I want are available into the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` Debian `stretch-backports` I have built the following Dockerfile based on the official Tensorflow Dockerfile.

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        nano \
        build-essential \
        curl \
        git \
        unzip \
        zip \
        libcurl3-dev \
        pkg-config \
        python-dev \
        software-properties-common \
        python3 \
        python3-dev \
        python3-pip

RUN apt-get install -t stretch-backports -y \
        nvidia-cuda-dev \
        nvidia-cuda-toolkit \
        && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Bazel

# Running bazel inside a `docker build` command causes trouble, cf:
#   https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/134
# The easiest solution is to set up a bazelrc file forcing --batch.
RUN echo "startup --batch" >>/etc/bazel.bazelrc
# Similarly, we need to workaround sandboxing issues:
#   https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/418
RUN echo "build --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone" \
    >>/etc/bazel.bazelrc

ENV BAZEL_VERSION 0.16.0
WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir /bazel && \
    cd /bazel && \
    curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36" -fSsL -O https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/$BAZEL_VERSION/bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh && \
    curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36" -fSsL -o /bazel/LICENSE.txt https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bazelbuild/bazel/master/LICENSE && \
    chmod +x bazel-*.sh && \
    ./bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh && \
    cd / && \
    rm -f /bazel/bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

# Tensorflow
WORKDIR /tensorflow
RUN git clone --branch=r1.8 --depth=1 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git .

# Configure the build for our CUDA configuration.

ENV TF_NEED_GCP=0 \
    TF_NEED_HDFS=0 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL=0 \
    TF_NEED_JEMALLOC=0 \
    TF_ENABLE_XLA=0 \
    TF_NEED_VERBS=0 \
    TF_CUDA_CLANG=0 \
    TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0 \
    TF_NEED_MKL=0 \
    TF_DOWNLOAD_MKL=0 \
    TF_NEED_MPI=0 \
    TF_NEED_S3=0 \
    TF_NEED_KAFKA=0 \
    TF_NEED_GDR=0 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \
    TF_SET_ANDROID_WORKSPACE=0 \
    TF_NEED_AWS=0 \
    CI_BUILD_PYTHON=python3 \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH \
    TF_NEED_TENSORRT=1 \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=1 \
    TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=3.5,5.2,6.0,6.1,7.0 \
    TF_CUDA_VERSION=9.1 \
    TF_CUDNN_VERSION=7 \
    CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} \
    tensorflow/tools/ci_build/builds/configured GPU \
    bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda \
    --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" \
        tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package && \
    bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/pip
```

My main problem is towards the end. Althogh I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH`, and `CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, Bazel is ignoring it, by returning `Invalid path to CUDA 9.1 toolkit. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudart.so.9.1 cannot be found`. There is an extra `/lib64/` which I do not know where it comes from. For the complete error see below.

By entering in the docker image I can see that the `libcudart.so.9.1` is in the given path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but I am not sure why Bazel insists on adding the `/lib64/` in front of it.

How can I force the path so that it stop adding the extra lib64?

Thanks in advance.

The error excerpt from Bazel installation on:

```
You have bazel 0.16.0 installed.
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages]
Invalid path to CUDA 9.1 toolkit. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudart.so.9.1 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 9.0]: 

Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 

Invalid path to CUDA 9.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 cannot be found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configure.py", line 1580, in <module>
    main()
  File "configure.py", line 1515, in main
    set_tf_cuda_version(environ_cp)
  File "configure.py", line 895, in set_tf_cuda_version
    _DEFAULT_PROMPT_ASK_ATTEMPTS)
__main__.UserInputError: Invalid TF_CUDA_SETTING setting was provided 10 times in a row. Assuming to be a scripting mistake.
The command '/bin/sh -c LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}     tensorflow/tools/ci_build/builds/configured GPU     bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda  --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"         tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package &&     bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/pip' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: One possible suggestion: Use a NVIDIA-provided install method for CUDA (rather than from debian stretch repos) and you will get an install structure for CUDA that bazel is expecting. Namely, that not everything is dumped into a single directory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/), but rather that there is a base path for the CUDA toolkit install, and a `lib64` directory hanging off the base path, which contains the libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RobertCrovella I will give it a try. What I wonder is why then the official Tensorflow Dockerfile for GPU installs `cudart` from the package manager instead of from NVIDIA resources https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel-gpu#L8-L13

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a package manager install.  But if you install `FROM debian:stretch` (what is in your question here) you are going to get different results than if you install `FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-base-ubuntu16.04`, which is what you linked in your comment. There should be no problem with the latter approach, but that is not what you have posted here in your question.  Furthermore, you are installing `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` which is debian package naming. NVIDIA doesn't create packages for CUDA starting with `nvidia-`.  The official TF Dockerfile looks fine to me.  Not yours.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella indeed, my problem is not related to the package manager, that is why my question has the "extra 'lib64'" in the title and not "why using nvidia-toolkit package does not work".